# Run a maven test-jar file for GroovyTestCase (junit)

Tags: maven, junit, jar, pom.xml, noclassdeffounderror

I have a maven project that contains 30 GroovyTestCase 'junit' test classes. I was able to generate the test-jar file that contains all the test classes, using http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html . However, every time I try to run the jar file using the following command:

```
java -cp target/groovy-tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar com.mycompany.TestClass
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 12 more
```

I have been struggling to find a way to generate the jar file so I can run all tests without the maven project.

Please let me know if there is another way to generate the jar file...